# Workaround for null pointer dereference?

Tags: c++, class, reference, c++17, nullptr

I am answering a programming question on [hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com), therefore the class code and anything outside the post-order function is not permitted. The question was a simple post-order traversal question. I am using c++ after some time, and since the class structure is written out with a pointer as the binary tree's left and right node, if I were to try and find the value of the neighbours of a tree node, and they happened to be null, I would get a segmentation error.

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

/* you only have to complete the function given below.  
Node is defined as  

class Node {
    public:
        int data;
        Node *left;
        Node *right;
        Node(int d) {
            data = d;
            left = NULL;
            right = NULL;
        }
};

*/


    void postOrder(Node *root) {
        if(root->left == nullptr && root->right == nullptr)
        {
            return;
        }
        
        postOrder(root->left);
        postOrder(root->right);
        cout << root->data << endl;
    }

}; //End of Solution
```

how would I go about this problem?

Comment: The workaround is: Don't dereference null pointers.

Comment: Check `root` instead of its children.

Comment: Both `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` and `using namespace std` are two habits you should kick right away. Use the headers you need. Embrace the `std::` prefix.

Answer (score 2):

`if(root->left == nullptr && root->right == nullptr)` is not a sufficient check for *either* being `nullptr`: so the behaviour of the program is undefined if exactly one of the nodes is `nullptr`.

```
if (root->left) postOrder(root->left);
if (root->right) postOrder(root->right);
```

is a fix; dropping the first `if` statement entirely.

Another fix might be to check instead `if (root)` at the beginning of the function itself, depending on how the function is called initially.

Answer (score 1):

You should check pointer before deferencing it:

```
void postOrder(const Node *root)
{
    if (root == nullptr) {
        return;
    }
    postOrder(root->left);
    postOrder(root->right);
    std::cout << root->data << std::endl;
}
```